Проблема в скане nmap
При такой команде nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24, пишет, что все 256 хостов активние, но столько устройств в сети нету.
Как так?

У вас что-нибудь наподобие tpws или прочих аналогов GoodbyeDPI случайно не установлено?

После такого скана посмотри таблицу arp.  Если на всех хостах один и тот же мак - там включен проксиарп. Весь трафик этот роутер тянет на себя.

Все вроде разние

как тогда сканить хости?

Значит они там есть по факту
